# How to toggle class when scrolled to multiple sections?

Tags: jquery

I have several sections on my page:

```
<header>
    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    ...other links go here
</header>
<section class="video">
</section>
<section class="our-products">
</section>
<section class="portfolio">
</section>
<section class="references">
</section>
<section class="our-team">
</section>
<section class="about-us">
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

Since the header is fixed to top and its background is transparent, while header links and logo are white, I need a way to add a class .dark to logo and header links in order to change their color in css when the sections with white background color scroll beneath them. Specifically, when the sections .our-products, .references, .our-team and .about-us, scroll beneath the header the class .dark should be added to logo and header links, while it should be removed when sections .video, .portfolio and footer scroll beneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scroll event handler on the window or document, that compares the current `scrollTop` of the body element to the positions of the sections in question. For ease of selection, I'd suggest giving a common class to those sections (I've used `"white"` in my demo).

This is pretty rough, but it is a starting place for you:

```js
var whiteSections = $("section.white")
var header = $("header")

$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop + 20
  var dark = false
  whiteSections.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    var top = $this.offset().top
    if (top <= scrollTop && top + $this.height() >= scrollTop) {
      dark = true
      return false
    }
  })
  header.toggleClass("dark", dark)
})
```

```css
body { background-color: grey; }
header { position: fixed; color: white; }
header.dark { color: black; }
footer { padding-top: 500px; }
section { min-height: 50px; }
.white { background-color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    ...other links go here
</header>
<section class="video">
The video section. The video section. The video section. The video section. 
</section>
<section class="our-products white">
Products. Products. Products. Products. Products. Products. 
</section>
<section class="portfolio">
Portfolio. Portfolio. Portfolio. Portfolio. Portfolio. 
</section>
<section class="references white">
References. References. References. References. References. References. 
</section>
<section class="our-team white">
Team. Our team. The team.
</section>
<section class="about-us white">
We're just a company, with a website, trying to help you out. Thanks for reading.
</section>
<footer>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis varius quam, in interdum massa finibus nec</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the job for you

```
$(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.our-products').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('.our-products').offset().top+$('.our-products').outerHeight() || $(this).scrollTop() >= $('.references').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('.references').offset().top+$('.references').outerHeight() || $(this).scrollTop() >= $('.our-team').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('.our-team').offset().top+$('.our-team').outerHeight()|| $(this).scrollTop() >= $('.about-us').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('.about-us').offset().top+$('.about-us').outerHeight() {
            $(".logo").addClass('dark');
        }
        else{
            $(".logo").removeClass('dark');
        }
    });
});
```

this checks if you are in the white sections which would be between their top and bottom (top+height) and adds the dark class and removes it from other sections.